# How to fill an array in python with given list of values and list of indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, tuples

What would be the simplest (fastest) way to take as input the following :

```
M=np.zeros((2,5))  
values=[a,b,c] #a,b and c are integers  
indices=[(1,2,4),(0,2,4)]
```

and have as an output :

```
M=[[0,a,b,0,c],[a,0,b,0,c]]
```

Comment: you mean `M=np.zeros((2,5))`?

Comment: So in your indices, the numbers in the tuples represent where the values go? (example: (0,2,4) -> [a, 0 , b, 0 ,c] correct?)

Comment: What do you mean by "simplest"? Shortest code? Most idiomatic? Least brainpower used to come up with a solution?

Comment: @Reti43 by simplest I mean fastest

Comment: @jasonmzx yes that is the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try indexing

```py
M = np.zeros((2,5))
values = [7,8,9]   
indices = np.array([[1,2,4],[0,2,4]])

M[np.arange(M.shape[0])[:,None],indices] = values

print(M)
```

```
[[0. 7. 8. 0. 9.]
 [7. 0. 8. 0. 9.]]
```